# Need to understand why code is not working, browser is not detecting location

Tags: javascript, webapi

the browser is not bringing the prompt the user's location and weather. app not functioning as well

i used a freenium api to build a weather app to detect location and weather, i expected the user's browser to detect location and display weather infomation but it is not functioning. below is my code

```js
function getWeather() {
  // Get the user's location.
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    // Get the weather forecast for the user's location.
    var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
      position.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.longitude +
      "&appid=YOUR_API_KEY";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onload = function() {
      // Parse the JSON response.
      var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      // Get the weather data.
      var temperature = response.main.temp;
      var description = response.weather[0].description;

      // Display the weather data.
      document.getElementById("weather-container").innerHTML =
        "Temperature: " + temperature + "°C<br>" +
        "Description: " + description;
    };
    request.send();
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  getWeather();
};
```

Comment: Is the browser immediately (without your intervention) denying the request or does nothing happen at all? The browser can deny the `geolocation` call without promting it to the user. Then you most likely have to send a `permissions-policy` header from your server to the client. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Permissions-Policy/geolocation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with Navigator.geoLocation.getCurrentPosition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532887/problem-with-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-not-working)